# Embedding Docusign Template On Webpage For Signing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docusignapi

I'm building a proof of concept for Docusign for my company, and I'm looking for some help.

It's a Ruby on Rails application, and I've been able to connect to the backend with the API using a gem. I can utilize the terminal to send out signature requests, but I need to now embed specific forms into a webpage that opens when you click a button just to show it can be done.

I can't find any sort of documentation on how to do this, and I'm hoping you guys can help me get it done. I know it's not much in the form of information, but there's really not much else I can say.

I'm connected to the API in my rails application on the backend, but now it's time to be able to open a document in a view via a button click that allows the signature.

Comment: are you planning to host the signing ceremony by opening envelope inside your app?

Comment: @AmitKBist Yes I am. That is exactly it. Basically, click a button, open the form within the app, sign, send, close.

Comment: Right now I have the API set to where I can put in commands in my Terminal to add to the database, access a template on Docusign and then send out a signature request. But I want it in house

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to host an embedded Signing ceremony then you need to create an `embedded signer` in the envelope. To make any signer an embedded Signer you must set the recipient's clientUserId property, which takes a string. This same clientUserId value will be used again in the [EnvelopeViews: createRecipient](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/) step when we generate the signing link.

[DocuSign Developer Center](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/signing-from-your-app) shows an example with code samples to achieve the embedded signing workflow.

Below JSON sample is at the time of creating an envelope, it shows how a signer will be an embedded signer, by populating clientUserId:

```
"signers": [
    {
            "email": "signeremail@email.com",
            "name": "Signer Name",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "routingOrder":1,
            "clientUserId":"12345"
    }
]
```

When your App wants to host the signing ceremony then it will call below URI and request body:

**URI:**

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient
```

**Body:**

```
{
  "authenticationMethod": "Password",
  "clientUserId": "12345",
  "email": "signeremail@email.com",
  "returnUrl": "https://yourapp.com",
  "userName": "Signer Name"
}
```